# Android List View Image Issue

Tags: android, xml

I have Created a Listview, and I am trying to add Images to some entries in the Listview. However when doing that I seem to get strange results, the Image appears much smaller than it should. Despite the fact that I have set its Width to Fill_Parent. Here is the XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

...

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/webImage"
    android:layout_below="@id/link"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp" />


<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sv"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/webImage"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/tag_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</HorizontalScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    ...

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the Result:
[image]

As you can see, the images are not showing up as intended and some are smaller than others. The Images should span across the entire screen.

Comment: Have you looked at it in Hierarchy Viewer http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html ?

Comment: I am very new to XML so I didnt know that even existed. I will look at it. But not sure it will help me. Im very new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ScaleType` for `ImageView`.`ImageView` is comes with different configuration options to support different scaleTypes. scaleType options are used for scaling the bounds of an image to the bounds of this view. Below are the listed scaleType configuration properties supported.

1. CENTER
2. CENTER_CROP
3. CENTER_INSIDE
4. FIT_CENTER
5. FIT_END
6. FIT_START
7. FIT_XY
8. MATRIX

Check here for more details
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: Thank you very much. Which one do you recommend for getting the desired result?

Comment: @TastyLemons, As i can see in xml, your ImageView is having `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`  `android:layout_height="wrap_content" ` , show you may use `FIT_XY`.

Comment: Ok when I do that the Image still has different heights sometimes. Can i set a specific height to make sure its always the same height?

Comment: yes, you should do like that. Or you may use height defined in `dimens.xml`, depend on device dpi.